# Job cannot access database after installed as Windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, quartz.net, job-scheduling

I can successfully run my jobs (that need access to an Sql Server database) when I run the Quartz.NET server in dev environment (Visual studio). But when I install the project as a Windows service, I get a `login failed` error to the database in my job. I have also allowed my service to interact with the desktop.
What am I not setting correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the Windows account your service is running under. Most probably it hasn't got the privileges to connect to your SQL Server, or to access the database. Basically, you have two choices:

1. Configure your service to run under an account that has a corresponding login in your SQL Server instance.
2. Add the account as a login in your SQL Server instance.